# Trying to change the 'data_directory' attribute in postgresql.conf file using awk command but keep receiving the syntax error

Tags: shell, awk

I need to change the 'data_directory' attribute in the postgresql.conf file permanently. I tried to get this done using *awk* command as shown below. (I have commented the existing attribute to make room for the new entry below.)

```
sudo awk '/data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'/ { print; print "data_directory = 'someDir/postgresql/10/main'"; next }1' /home/ubuntu/postgresql.conf
```

But I receive the syntax error right below the first *print* as shown below.

```
awk: cmd. line:1: /data_directory = /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/ { print; print "data_directory = AquilaData/postgresql/10/main"; next }1
awk: cmd. line:1:                                                ^ syntax error
```

Can't figure out why. Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Edit: I need to retain the single quotes around directory path.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and copy in the verbatim error message as text, not as an image.

Comment: What shell are you using and how does your shell make a difference between single quotes for the `awk` invocation and single quotes meant for the `awk` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there are two issues to take care - 1. Single quote, 2. that '/' in the path.

I defined a sample test.conf as below, /var/lib will be replaced with /sample inside the single quotes.

```
$ cat test.conf
data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'
```

Then defined two variables

```
$ SRC="data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'"
$ DST="data_directory = '/sample/postgresql/10/main'"
```

Single line sed command does the job. I used '+' as separator and double quote for sed.

```
$ sed -i "s+$SRC+$DST+g" test.conf
```

See the result.

```
$ cat test.conf
data_directory = '/sample/postgresql/10/main'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
/data_directory = /var/lib/postgresql/10/main/
```

The filter command works as `/string/`. There are multiple `/` characters in the string you want to filter - you need to escape them. Try:

```
/data_directory = \/var\/lib\/postgresql\/10\/main/
```

The `\/` tells `awk` that this `/` is not the end of filter command, but it's a part of string to filter.

```
sudo awk '/data_directory = \/var\/lib\/postgresql\/10\/main/ { print "data_directory = someDir/postgresql/10/main"; next }1' /home/ubuntu/postgresql.conf
```

However I would probably go with:

```
awk -v VAR="someDir/postgresql/10/main" '/^data_directory = /{ print "data_directory = ",VAR; next; }1'
```

A example can be found on [tutorialspoint](http://tpcg.io/uF5gSr).

Comment: Tried both variations you suggested but I couldn't get it working for me. Problem is I don't know enough to debug the issues. Request you to verify your suggestions. The last one keeps waiting for my inputs and the first one (with escape) only displays the content of .conf file and doesn't make the desired change. Even if it does, I need it to store the changes in the file instead of printing it as stdout.

Comment: I have added an example on external site with some usage example.

Answer (score 1):

`/` is used to enclose a test with regex, but `/` char is found in the pathname `/var/lib/postgresql/10/main`, this is why this is causing the syntax error.

Either try to define a variable `line` in the `BEGIN` which is executed only once before actually parsing the file:

```
sudo awk 'BEGIN { line="data_directory = '/var/lib/postgresql/10/main'" } ; $0 ~ line { ....
```

Or escape the `/` in the pathname used in the regex:

```
udo awk '/data_directory = '[/]var[/]lib[/]postgresql[/]10[/]main'/ { ...
```

Comment: Hey Jay, I tried escaping / the way you suggested. 

    `sudo awk '/data_directory = '[/]var[/]lib[/]postgresql[/]10[/]main'/ { print; print "data_directory = 'someDir/postgresql/10/main"; next }1' postgresql.conf
>`


But it keeps waiting for my input. I don't know what to fix.